# How to get puppeteer accessibility tree of iframe content

Tags: accessibility, puppeteer

I'm using `puppeteer.accessibility.snapshot()` to obtain an accessibility tree snapshot of a full page with an iframe. However, I can't see the accessible elements inside the iframe.

`Accessibility.getFullAXTree` in the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Accessibility/#method-getFullAXTree) does not help either because it only shows the iframe element too.

I cannot snapshot an`iframe.contentFrame()` because it does not have accessibility methods

`await page.accessibility.snapshot({ root: await page.$("iframe") })` returns null even though `await page.$("iframe")`  is an element handle

How do I get the accessibility tree of the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the dev tools protocol to get the Accessibility tree manually

```js
async function retrieveIframeAxTreeFromJS({ page, jsIframeSelectorExpresson }) {
  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    await client.send("Accessibility.enable");
  const {
    result: { objectId: iframeId },
  } = await client.send("Runtime.evaluate", {
    expression: jsIframeSelectorExpresson,
  });
  const iframeNodeDescribed = await client.send("DOM.describeNode", {
    objectId: iframeId,
  });

  return await client.send("Accessibility.getFullAXTree", {
    frameId: iframeNodeDescribed.node.frameId,
  });
}
```

Then I rewrote the [Accessibility class](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/ea2f6b8ee76e4af872e5df157bff2ad9a49936f1/packages/puppeteer-core/src/cdp/Accessibility.ts#L251) to use it in it's own.

```js
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(`page with iframe`);
  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await client.send("Accessibility.enable");

  const newAccesbilityClass = new Accessibility(client);
 
  console.log(
    await newAccesbilityClass.snapshot({
      tree: await retrieveIframeAxTreeFromJS({
        page,
        jsIframeSelectorExpresson: "document.querySelector('iframe')",
      }),
    }),
```